# Hidden Google Doc iframe won't load

Tags: iframe, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

On my webpage, I've got several tabs and, in one of them, I want to display an iframe containing a Google Doc. 
When the iframe is displayed, the google doc is loaded and there is no problem.
But by default, this tab is hidden (so, the iframe inside too)

Something like

```
<div id="tab-1">...</div>
<div id="tab-2" hidden>...</div>
<div id="tab-3" hidden><iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/......../edit?usp=sharing&embed=true"></iframe></div>
```

with jquery to handle actions

And, when the iframe is hidden, it seems like it can't load until it's not hidden anymore. The problem is I endlessly get popup saying

> This error has been reported to Google and will be examined as soon as possible. To continue, please refresh the page.

---

- In a page without tab, if the iframe has the "hidden" attribute, the bug occurs too
- I could get around the problem by "hiding" the iframe with a "heigth=0" but when it's hidden in a tab, the problem comes back

Have you ever met this problem and find a way to solve it ? Do I have to "dynamically load" the google doc iframe when it becomes visible ? (And then, how to ?)
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried css styles to hide element(s). Eg. style="display: none;" or style="visibility:hidden;"

Comment: It works with "visibility:hidden;" (I guess i have to change css height and width, to remove the big empty blocks ?) but not "display: none"

Answer (score 0):

I don't mind if the iframe is loaded later so I decided to load the `<iframe>` with jquery, when the tab is opened, by storing the src into the attributes.

There could be problems though, if the tab is closed while the iframe is not fully loaded. 
That's why I prevent this by stop loading if the tab is changed, (and don't if it's already fully loaded.)

html

```
<iframe data-src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/......" 
        class="google-doc"></iframe>
```

jquery

```
//Stops iframe loading
$(".tab-to-close iframe.google-doc").not('.isloaded').prop('src','')

//Change the tabs
$(".tab-to-close").hide();
$(".tab-to-open").show();

var iframetoload = $(".tab-to-open iframe.google-doc");

//Load iframes on the new tab
iframetoload.prop('src',iframetoload.data('src'))

//If it's loaded in time, save it so it's not destroyed on tab changing
iframtetoload.on('load', function(){
   $(this).addClass('isloaded');
});
```